# What would you call a person who keeps on boasting about himself and is jealous of others' achievements?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have come through some words like schadenfreude and envy, but am still looking for a better word or a phrase, or a group of words that will do the trick.

Actually I'm trying to explain the nature of a character in a story; for that purpose I need a sentence which describes the character.

Comment: you call him "boastful" and "jealous".  Couldn't be simpler.

Comment: This question is often dealt with on EL&L. Search "envious", "jealous" , "boast".

Answer (score 1):

A person who boasts of his achievements is a braggart; someone envious of the station of others is an envier.

Schadenfreude means taking joy in the pain of others, which is different from braggadocio or jealousy.

Comment: 'Envier' is rare. No native speaker would use that word. You'd just say 'that person is very envious of others'.

Answer (score 1):

"A strutting, covetous man."

"X held forth on her successes to anyone who would listen, but routinely slighted and impugned the accomplishments of others." (This sentence does not directly say jealousy but the implication is there and can be described further as you develop the character.)